# Is it possible to get the inserted row's ID using hooks in sequelize?

Tags: sequelize.js

I want to generate unique order number for each order. I am trying to nest created order's id inside order number. 
There are hooks in sequelize described in the [docs](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/hooks.html) .
*Is it possible to do using any of these hooks?*
I use `beforeCreate()` and `beforeUpdate()` to hash password before saving.

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Order = sequelize.define('Order', {
    buyer_id: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
    order_status_code: DataTypes.TINYINT.UNSIGNED,
    order_detail: DataTypes.TEXT,
    order_date: DataTypes.DATE
  }, { 
     hooks: {
          beforeSave: function(order, options) {
            order.order_number = order.order_id + "UNIQUE"
     }
}
});
  Order.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
    Order.hasOne(models.OrderItem,{foreignKey: "order_id"})
  };
  return Order;
};
```

**Update** 
I tried below method, but It's not working. Hook is running but row is not being updated.

```
    module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Order = sequelize.define('Order', {
    buyer_id: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
    order_status_code: DataTypes.TINYINT.UNSIGNED,
    order_detail: DataTypes.TEXT,
    order_date: DataTypes.DATE
  }, {
    hooks:{
      afterCreate: function(order, options) {
        order.update({
          order_number : 'OD' + Date.now + order.id + order.OrderItem.product_id + order.buyer_id
        })
      }
    }
   });
  Order.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
    Order.hasOne(models.OrderItem,{foreignKey: "order_id"})
  };
  return Order;
};
```

Comment: you have to use afterCreate() so you will get the id then update the orderId.

Comment: so I have to update the created row inside the hook?

Comment: yes. In the afterCreate() you will receive the row and you can update It and make sure you are now using afterUpdate() for this it will keep on updating forever :P

Comment: I found a method in the docs for this that also enables transactions. "A Note About Transactions Sections" https://sequelize.org/master/manual/hooks.html

Comment: Sorry guys, My bad. I didn't set the `order_number` in the model.

Comment: @krishnasapkal Can you explain what do you mean? I didn't get you. I think I might get into loop If I use `afterUpdate` but here I am using `afterCreate`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried below method and I discovered a lot of things that can be done inside a model definition.

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
 const Order = sequelize.define('Order', {
   buyer_id: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
   order_status_code: DataTypes.TINYINT.UNSIGNED,
   order_detail: DataTypes.TEXT,
   order_date: DataTypes.DATE,
   order_number: DataTypes.STRING(20)
 }, {
   hooks:{
     afterCreate:  async function(order, options) {
     await order.update(
       {
         order_number : 'OD' + Date.now() + order.id + order.OrderItem.product_id + order.buyer_id
       },
       {
         transaction: options.transaction
       })
     }
   }
  });
 Order.associate = function(models) {
   // associations can be defined here
   Order.hasOne(models.OrderItem,{foreignKey: "order_id"})
 };
 return Order;
};
```

So, When a user creates a order. I use transaction to insert the data in two tables. That's why I can access `order.OrderItem.product_id` inside the hook.
*But if you want to access any other model, you can always use `sequelize.models.YourModel`* 
I am using `async` and `await` because I also want the `order_number` in the response. I achieve this by passing the transaction in the hook. 
 If anyone finds a better approach please suggest.